# Can i deploy MOSS based webparts on ASP.NET web form and how

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

i need to know, if we can deploy webparts that are created in MOSS for MOSS on a ASP.NET page and use them. Or is there any way of using the webparts with MOSS.

TIA,
Nimish

Answer (score 3):

If the webparts created for SharePoint, are SharePoint specific, and rely on SharePoint Functionality, then they will only operate on a SharePoint server (or an ASP.NET server, with access to the SharePoint server, depending on the webpart).

However, Webparts created in ASP.NET, can (typically) be used within SharePoint.

Note: SharePoint, comprises both MOSS (Microsoft Office SharePoint Server) and WSS (Windows SharePoint Server).

Answer (score 1):

When you create a webpart "for MOSS", you create a control which inherits `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts`. So, actually, you write a webpart "for ASP.NET" and can also execute it inside WSS/MOSS.

Please, read this links as they provides more informations on subject:

1. [ASP.NET Web Parts controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0s9t4ck.aspx)
2. [Building an ASP.NET 2.0 Web Part for Deployment to WSS V3.0 and MOSS 2007](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/060914.htm)

Comment: SO i want to deploy/use a web part created for MOSS on ASP.NET, is it possible?

Comment: cool, how, can i just use the webparts dll's and add them as normal server controls on asp.net web form. can you guide to some online knowledgebase for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can **not** use SharePoint web parts in a plain ASP.NET site. Most Sharepoint web parts heavily rely on the (extra) functionality that SharePoint server provides. Without SharePoint they will not work.